# Pass Selected Dropdown Value to Controller using a Button

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

In the example below when clicking the button the value selected in the dropdownlist should be passed to the controller, but its not.  How can I pass the value?

View:

```
@model BillingModel
...
<select id="ddl" asp-for="SelectedCompanyID" asp-items="Model.Companies" class="form-control"></select>

<a asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Invoice" asp-route-id="@Model.SelectedCompanyID" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"></span> Create Invoice</a>
....
```

Model:

```
public class BillingModel
{
    public int SelectedCompanyID { get; set; }       

    public SelectList Companies { get; set; }    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your link is using razor code to specify the route `id` value which is server side code. It does not change on the client side just because a option is selected.

Either use a form that makes a GET and submits the option value

```
<form asp-controller="Invoice" asp-action="Create" method="get">
    <select id="ddl" asp-for="SelectedCompanyID" asp-items="Model.Companies" class="form-control"></select>
    <input type="submit" value="Create Invoice" /> // you can style this to look like your link if you want
</form>
```

Note that this will generate the url with a query string value for the `id`, not a route value (i.e. it will generate `../Invoice/Create?id=1`, not `../Invoice/Create/1`)

Alternatively, you could use javascript/jquery to make the redirect by building a url based on the selected option

```
<a id="create" href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Create Invoice</a>

$('#create').click(function() {
    var baseUrl = '@Url.Action("Create", "Invoice")';
    location.href = baseUrl + '/' + $('#SelectedCompanyID').val();
}
```

Comment: Excellent thanks,  would you mind elaborating more on the query string vs route value bit?  I don't understand what the effect of either will be.

Comment: I think when it's query string, then it can be mapped in the controller's action (parameter name should match `id` in this case).

Comment: When you use a form to make a GET, the values of any form controls are always added to the url as query string values - the browser has no knowledge of your routes so it cannot generate `../Invoice/Create/1` (which the `href` attribute in your current link would generate assuming your using the default routes). Instead it generates `../Invoice/Create?id=1`

Comment: Both will hit the controller method and pass the value of the selected option. The only difference is how its displayed in the browsers address bar when you make the redirect.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Also, Value can be sent via `$.get("/Invoice/Create", {id: button.attr("asp-route-id")})...`. Kindly correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Unbreakable, That is an ajax call and means the user will stay on the same page, but OP wants to make a redirect. Also its not sending back the selected option.