# SelectListItem Dropdown not returning value to the controller?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor, entity-framework-core

I have a DropDownList that is not returning value selected to the controller. I am using SelectListItem in my model for the list items and an a GroupType which is part of an enum to store the value. I am using asp-route-groupType to return the value to the controller. Oddly enough this seems to work similarly for other dropdowns but not this one...I am able to send the userName from the model(not part of the dropdown), but not the groupType. I am using ASP.NET Core and the entity framework.

I have tried changing the type of what am putting the asp-route-groupId with no luck.

HTML:

```
<strong>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.GroupType)</strong>
<select asp-for="GroupType">
@foreach (var opt in Model.Group)
{
    <option value="@opt.Value">@opt.Text</option>
}
</select>   
<br />
<a asp-action="ChangeGroup" asp-controller="Station" asp-route-userName="@Model.UserName" asp-route-groupType="@Model.GroupType.ToString()">Assign Group</a>
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult ChangeGroup(string userName, string groupType)
{
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(ViewApp));
}
```

Model:

```
public class AdminViewApplicationViewModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Group { get; set; }
    public GroupType GroupType { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I add the values for the select list in a manager:

```
model.Group = new List<SelectListItem>();
model.Group.Add(new SelectListItem {
    Text = "Group1",
    Value = GroupType.Group1.ToString()
});
model.Group.Add(new SelectListItem {
    Text = "Group2",
    Value = GroupType.Group2.ToString()
});
```

The controller should return the value selected from the dropdown in parameter described in the above code.

Comment: No, I haven't actually, can you post how I would use that?

Comment: You should be using a form instead for that solution to work. The problem is `asp-route-groupType="@Model.GroupType.ToString()"`. Your `@Model.GroupType.ToString()` simply returns the base ToString if not overriden should be Enumerable GroupType / ClassName?

Comment: Oh, it is inside a form, that's why I thought it had something to do with with my asp-route, because userName does get passed to the controller. I get string 0 for groupType.

Comment: Hmm okay.. Try removing your asp-route-grouptype and in your controller set `string userName, GroupType GroupType` and change your select to something like `<select asp-for="GroupType" asp-items="Model.Group"></select>`

Comment: I tried that and no luck, still sends 0. Why would I want to remove asp-route-grouptype? How will it send that value to the controller?

Comment: @D.Dahlberg Looks like I needed the form to submit, I will mark Xing Zou answer as the the way to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Model.GroupType.ToString()` will not change when you select value and it always equals to the value passed from action

You could use a form that makes a GET and submits the option value

```
<form asp-action="ChangeGroup" asp-controller="Station" method="get">
<strong>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.GroupType)</strong>
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserName)
<select asp-for="GroupType">
    @foreach (var opt in Model.Group)
    {
        <option value="@opt.Value">@opt.Text</option>
    }
</select>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Assign Group" />
</form>
```

You could also use the onclick in javascript/jquery event gets the value and submits it:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserName)
<strong>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.GroupType)</strong>
<select id="gt">
    @foreach (var opt in Model.Group)
    {
        <option value="@opt.Value">@opt.Text</option>
    }
</select>
<br />
<a id="as" onclick="Assign()">Assign Group</a>
@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Assign() {
            var userName = $("#UserName").val();
            var groupType = $("#gt option:selected").val();
            console.log(userName);
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Station/ChangeGroup',
                type: 'Get',
                data: {
                    userName: userName, groupType: groupType
                },
                success: function () {

                },
                complete: function () {

                },
            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

Refer to [Pass Selected Dropdown Value to Controller using a Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45451277/pass-selected-dropdown-value-to-controller-using-a-button)

Comment: Looks like I needed the form to submit the values, thanks!