# trigger IActionResult using Ajax request in Net Core 3.1 MVC

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

***SOLVED, see end of the post.***

I have the following `.Net Core 3.1` project, where videos are displayed for a user. It can also select playlists, which holds subsets of those videos.
Once a user selects the playlist from a `SelectList` element, I would like it to send the playlist ID to the backend, load the videos and load the view again.
However, I would like to have no submit button with my `SelectList`, once a playlist is selected it should load the videos.

I tried this with Ajax, and it works so far that it sends the playlist ID to a backend method, loads the videos, but then returns the ajax call to the browser.

Controller:

```
public async<IActionResult> Index(string playlistId = null)
{
    // process playlistID and other stuff in viewModel
    return View(viewModel);
}


[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> ProcessIncomingAjaxRequest([FromBody] string data)
{
     playlistId = String.IsNullOrEmpty(data) ? "0" : data;
     return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index), new { playlistId= playlistId });   
}
```

Ajax call:

```
$('#PlaylistId').on('change',function () {
    var name = $('#PlaylistId').val()          
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/ProcessIncomingAjaxRequest",
        data: JSON.stringify(name),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error.status);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

`ProcessIncomingAjaxRequest` gets called by the Ajax request, calls the `RedirectToAction` method, both methods go through all the steps and then returns to the browser with the 200 response from the Ajax call, not loading the actual View.

Is there a way to call the View method (`index()`) from `ProcessIncomingAjaxRequest` in the Controller and resume the normal way of loading the view?

Solution:
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45451277/pass-selected-dropdown-value-to-controller-using-a-button) answered my question

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `the normal way of loading the view`. The `RedirectToAction` just works in the normal way ***and*** the client-side ajax handler ***should*** work in the normal way as well (at least `jQuery ajax` handles redirection correctly). With your posted code, the returned result is the executed result from `View(viewModel)` (which should be some html). Isn't that what you want?

Comment: when the code comes to return View(viewModel), it gets returned to the client, shows the alert(response) from the JQuery, but doesn't load the page with the data from the viewModel.